# Google Cloud managed service for Prometheus consistently ingests wrong values for certain metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

We set up google cloud managed service for prometheus this week. While creating grafana dashboards I noticed that most metrics were ingested correctly, but some values were consistently incorrect.

The output of the metrics endpoint looks like this (truncated):

```
# HELP channel_socket_bytes_received_total Number of bytes received from clients # TYPE channel_socket_bytes_received_total counter # HELP event_collection_size Number of elements # TYPE event_collection_size gauge event_collection_size{name="interest"} 18 event_collection_size{name="rfq"} 362 event_collection_size{name="negotiation"} 12 # TYPE sq_firestore_read_total counter sq_firestore_read_total{collection="negotiation"} 12 sq_firestore_read_total{collection="rfq_interest"} 18 sq_firestore_read_total{collection="rfq"} 362
```

The output on this endpoint is generated by `"prom-client": "14.1.0"`.

Google managed service for prometheus ingests these metrics. Almost all of them work as expected. But the `sq_firestore_read_total` metric is consistently wrong.

The google cloud metrics explorer shows these values:
[image: Metrics explorer for sq_firestore_read_total]

Services were restarted a number of times. Once the value of one label reached 3, but more common is that the values of all 3 labels of the metric stay stuck at 0.

It seems to me that something goes wrong during the ingestion stage. Is this a bug in the google cloud managed service for prometheus?

Important to reiterate: The values I expect are 12, 16, and 362. The values that are ingested are either 0 and sometimes 3.

Comment: i found this: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/troubleshooting#counter-sums

i find that the values update very slowly in general